# Cannot deploy .NET app to app engine - kaniko-projec executor error

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am getting crazy with this error when deploying an App Engine dotnetcore3 app:

```
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:0bbaa4859eec9796d32ab45e6c1627562dbc7796e40450295b9604cd3f4197af" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 137
```

I have no idea to get around it nor have found any info. I do not want to use the kaniko thing or anything else, I just need ANY way to deploy my app.

I have tried setting older version (0.12.0) according to this, I think it helped in the past but does not help now:
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/807

Kind thanks for any help.

Here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 15
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
  target_concurrent_requests: 100
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

Comment: Part of your app.yaml is for App Engine Standard and not for Flexible. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/reference/app-yaml

Comment: The `step exited with non-zero status: 137` is most likely related to [memory issues](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/troubleshooting/common-issues/error-code-137/) that are happening when your app is being built with Cloud Build.

Is it possible that you have many dependencies? could you remove some that may be unnecessary?